# Cinema Display Arm

Tags: cinema-display

What kind of arm do I need to hold up a large cinema display? The back of the display doesn't have a standard 4 screw mounting bracket.

I understand it would need some type of way to remove the built in mount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple makes a VESA mount adapter kit that replaces the stand and attaches to a 100mm x 100mm standard VESA mount (i.e. pretty much any standard LCD mounting arm).

I can only find the [more recent model](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD179ZM/A) on Apple's Store, that works with 24 or 27 inch iMacs and LED displays. There's an older model that works with the older Cinema displays (the aluminum body ones), but it doesn't look like Apple stocks it any more.